# longest increasing subsequence of a [1 2 .. N] permutation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, permutation

Here is the problem:

Given an array of N elements (1 to N), sort the array with one constraint: you can only move an element to begin of the array or end of the array. How many moves do you at least need to sort the array?

For example: `2 5 3 4 1` => `1 2 5 3 4` => `1 2 3 4 5`, so I need at least 2 moves.

I figure out one solution: `N - length of longest increasing subsequence`, in above example the answer if `5 - 3 = 2`.

I know a `O(NlogN)` algorithm to find longest increasing subsequence (LIS). But with elements in the array being in `[1, N]`, I wonder is there a `O(N)` solution to find LIS of the array?

Or is there a `O(N)` solution to solve the initial problem given that we know elements are from 1 to N?

Comment: Do you want to sort the array or find the LIS?

Comment: I just want to know the least number of moves to make the array sorted. I found if the length of LIS is known, the problem is solved. So what I am asking is a O(N) solution given the special elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the longest increasing sequence where the difference between any two consecutive elements is `1`.

Just finding the longest increasing sequence is not enough, for example with `1 5 3 4 2` the longest inc seq has length `3` but the problem can only be solved in `3` steps not `2` as far as I can tell.

To find the longest inc seq where the difference is `1` in `O(N)` time and `O(N)` space can be done by allocating a `helper` array of size `N` initialized to all `0` for example. This array will store at position `i` the length of the longest subsequence up `i` and if `i` hasn't been seen yet it will be `0`.

Then you go through the unsorted array and when you find an element `x` you set `helper[x] = helper[x-1] + 1` and you update a `max` variable.

Finally, the cost to sort is `input_array.length - max`

Example:

```
array:   3 1 2
         0 1 2 3
helper:  0 0 0 0
max = 0

step 1:
check element at position 1 which is 3. helper[3] = helper[3 - 1] + 1 == 1:
          0 1 2 3
helper:   0 0 0 1
max = 1

step 2:
check element at position 2 which is 1. helper[1] = helper[1 - 1] + 1 == 1:
          0 1 2 3
helper:   0 1 0 1
max = 1

step 3:
check element at position 3 which is 2. helper[2] = helper[2 - 1] + 1 == 2:
          0 1 2 3
helper:   0 1 2 1
max = 2

cost = 3 - 2 = 1
```

Comment: emm.. what do you mean by the length of the sequence up i?

Comment: the length of the subsequence of increasing elements that contains `i` as the last element and where every two consecutive elements have a difference of `1`. I'll add an example.

Comment: @justmscs added an example and edited a mistake I had in the original idea